# How does adding instances to a Array work in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am following along a tutorial and I am confused with why there are () at the end of the array which will hold instances of Car.

```
class CarModel {
    
    var cars = [Car]()
    
    init () {
       ... 
    }
    
}
```

Can someone explain how this is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most initialisers can be used without typing the `.init` name. So `let someObject = SomeType.init()` would be the same as `let someObject = SomeType()`.

`Array` has an empty initialiser that will create an empty array.

```
// let emptyCarArray = Array<Car>.init()
let emptyCarArray = Array<Car>()
```

However, Swift also has a syntax shortcut for `Array<Element>` which is `[Element]`. So the above code is exactly the same as doing...

```
// let emptyCarArray = [Car].init()
let emptyCarArray = [Car]()
```

This can also be done by explicitly setting the type too...

```
let emptyCarArray: Array<Car> = []
let emptyCarArray: [Car] = []
```

All four lines of code in this do the same thing.